# Is it possible to step through a React Navigation stack navigator without specifying route names?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

Most of the detail is in the title question. I'm not exactly struggling to navigate between screens, but I'm wondering if push/pop (or something else) can be used to step through a stack without identifying specific routes. So if I have a stack with a bunch of screens, can they have a button with something to the effect of

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.push()}>
    <Text>Next</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Or is this a complete misuse of push? The object here is to be able to change the order of the stack quickly in development without having to go through all of the screens and adjust the button paths. So if the screens are simply named 1, 2, 3, and 4 and I want to move 2 to the end (3 becomes 2, 4 becomes 3), I have to update the next/back button routes for screens 2, 3, and 4. Whereas if they are all coded as "next" or "back", all I do is cut and paste screen 2 after screen 4 in the stack navigator definition. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the list of names, find the next name, and then push that. Define a helper like this:

```js
const pushNext = () => state => {
  // Get the current route name
  const currentRouteName = state.routes[state.index].name;

  // Get the index of the current route in the route name list
  const currentRouteIndex = state.routeNames.indexOf(currentRouteName);

  // Get the next item in the route name list
  const nextRouteName = state.routeNames[currentRouteIndex + 1];

  if (nextRouteName) {
    // If there was a next route, return a push action
    return StackActions.push(nextRouteName);
  } else {
    // Reset to current state for noop or whatever you want
    return CommonActions.reset(state);
  }
};
```

Then use it in your components:

```js
navigation.dispatch(pushNext());
```